# Classifying endomorphisms of $k[x]$ which are automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, reference-request

Let $k$ be a field and let $\phi\colon k[x]\to k[x]$ be a $k$-linear ring homomorphism. I think the following is true but I am looking for a detailed proof or reference:

> There exists an element $r\in k[x]$ satisfying $\phi(r)=x$ if and only if $\deg \phi(x)=1$.

EDIT:

I see this question was downvoted, perhaps I should add more context. This is not a homework question or anything of that sort - although if someone knows of a textbook or course that uses this as an exercise, just a reference to this would be enough to answer my question. As a secondary remark, assuming the result is correct, I am wondering under which conditions on a ring $R$ the result continues to hold with $R$ in place of $k$.

Comment: Observe (Prove!) that $\varphi(k) \subseteq k$ and the action of $\varphi$ on $k$ and $x$ determines $\varphi$ completely.

Comment: @QiZhu yes, that is clear - it is not the difficult part of the question, in my opinion.

Comment: But that immediately resolves the question?

Comment: The part I was referring to is the degree considerations, namely that composing two functions multiplies the degree, which seems like a slightly messy calculation if one puts in all the details. This is fully hidden in the answer I accepted, but is the essence in my opinion.

Comment: Again, it is immediate for fields $k$. You are right though that it is messier for arbitrary rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the following statements are all equivalent for any field $k$:

> 1. There is $r\in k[x]$ such that $\phi(r)=x$.
> 2. $\phi$ is surjective.
> 3. $\deg\phi(x)=1$.

Showing 1 to 2 and 3 to 1 is obvious, so I will leave it as your own.

Now assume that $\deg\phi(x)>1$. By observing the term of the highest order, we can see that $\phi(r)>0$ for any *nonconstant* $r\in k[x]$. Therefore, no $r\in k[x]$ satisfy $\phi(r)=x$, so $\phi$ is not surjective.

It is easy to see that $\phi$ is not surjective when $\deg\phi(x)<1$. Therefore, the surjectivity of $\phi$ implies $\deg\phi(x)=1$.

Comment: "Now assume that $\deg \phi(x)>1$." I would have preferred to see the calculation you are doing spelled out in detail, and I am curious for which rings this part of the argument goes through.

Comment: @pre-kidney The detail is quite simple: if $f(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots + a_1x+a_0$ is a polynomial, then $\phi(f)= a_n\phi(x)^n+\cdots + a_0$. If $\phi(x)$ is of degree $m$, then $\phi(x)^n$ has of degree $mn$.

Comment: @pre-kidney The implication $1\to 2$ and $2\to 3$ works for any commutative ring. However, we need $k$ is a field when proving $3\to 1$.